# VS Code prevent Go to symbol from displaying the result at the center of the screen

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using either `Go to symbol in Editor...` or `Go to symbol in Workspace...` VS Code, the selected symbol at the center of the screen. Is there a way to put the symbol at the top of the screen?

I'm currently using `vscode-neovim` and using the `zt` shortcut to make the cursor line at the top of the screen right after pressing enter but that's a bit annoying.

Answer (score 2):

This is already *kind of sort of* done (just not "to the degree" that you want). Work on enabling it happened in PR [Reveal closer to top (center body, not signature) #80727](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/80727), and since that PR, `TextEditorSelectionRevealType.NearTop` and `TextEditorSelectionRevealType.NearTopIfOutsideViewport` are being used in more places, including the one this question is about- go-to-symbol (which includes all of going to definitions, declarations, references, etc.) courtesy of PR [Consider adopting TextEditorSelectionRevealType.NearTop for other actions #90068](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90068).

If you look at the current state of the source code, it's not super flexible. The type of `TextEditorSelectionRevealType` is hardcoded on a somewhat case-by-case basis, and [at the time of this writing, there is no option to reveal at the top](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1c0c4726d30a0574739b35cc6d7a7dea9b3decb2/src/vs/platform/editor/common/editor.ts#L300). To get what you want, I'd imagine go-to-symbol would need to provide a setting for what `TextEditorSelectionRevealType` to use, and a `TextEditorSelectionRevealType` added for revealing at the top. So really the answer for you is that you should [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) (or a PR of your own).

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the first linked issue ticket by googling "`github vscode issues go to definition top of screen`" (the rest was found from browsing source code and git blames).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.